# Postfix route unknown users (ONLY!) to default address

Tags: postfix

I use postfix and would like to route all emails which are NOT configured to got to a fallback address. Is that possible? So e.g.

john@email.com -> configured in virtual file and is read by user account john
bill@email.com -> is NOT configured as a user and has no entry in the virtual table -> should be added to the mail box: unknown_users@email.com

Thanks in advance

Leon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is different for local and virtual addresses.

For local addresses, you can use `luser_relay`; this takes a single fallback address.

For virtual addresses, use `virtual_alias_maps` to add wildcards *per recipient domain*.

I should warn you that using catchalls is not recommended, as you cannot properly reject mail; in fact, you will never reject **any**  mail with such a setup, and bouncing them later will produce backscatter spam (and gets you blacklisted PDQ.)